# How to make Drupal webforms with radio buttons and checkboxes validate in html5

Tags: forms, drupal, radio-button, label

Drupal webforms with radio buttons and/or checkboxes do not validate, because "The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control". How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
        $form['research_rotation_first_choice'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radio',
        '#value' => '',
        '#title' => t('First Choice'),
        '#attributes' => array('name' => array('first_choice')),
    );
```

That is an example of how I am using validated attributes.

Comment: Okayyy, but I think you have mis-understood my question. This is not about form validation, but about validating the HTML as valid HTML5...